# Currently facing issue of very low performance in react application

Tags: reactjs, performance, google-chrome, lighthouse

We are not able to figure out what changes we need to do to improve react application performance. the score shown by the lighthouse is 5.
Any help provided would be appreciated.
The scripting of react application take 6 seconds.[image]

[image]

Comment: check same thing after build project

Comment: after build the score still remain 5.

Comment: use Profiler and check which component take more time to load and optimize it accordingly : https://reactjs.org/docs/profiler.html